# Background image outside of wrapper div, at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I need to place a horizontal background image at the bottom of the page. What I have works fine granted the div "wrapper" is filled with a lot of content and the users scroll bar appears.

The problem arises on some pages that have little content, and the wrapper div is short, I need to keep the image at the bottom.

Here is the faulty page in practice http://www.rmcl-usa.com/

The tree image just needs to be at the bottom. Again it is not a problem when the wrapper div extends passed the users resolution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following CSS on your footer div:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
```

Make sure it is declared before your other divs, such that it is the lowest in the z-index.

Comment: I can't get this to implement correctly. When you say footer div, do you mean the div of the background image? Is this solution basically forcing a short div to extend to the bottom regardless of the amount of content? Apologies

Comment: When I say footer div, I mean whatever div is wrapping your footer image. I say this because we all know you used proper style and wrapped your footer in a div. Also, no, this is not stretching anything. This is 'floating' your div to the bottom. It will retain whatever height you set on it, but it will stretch width-wise to the sides of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Move the bottom image div to the bottom right before the body close and do:

```
<div id="bottomimage" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;z-index:-10;position:fixed;">
```

doing just:

```
position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0;left: 0;
```

didn't do it for me in firefox.